# Injecting many payloads at once (node-red)

Tags: node.js, node-red

I have a problem. I'm new to node red, I want to inject many payloads with different topics at once. I wanted to do it with function like in first node. It's function looks like so:

```
msg.topic="ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[0];datatype=String"
msg.payload=global.get("nazwa")
return msg
msg.topic="ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[1];datatype=String"
msg.payload=global.get("nazwa2")
return msg
...
msg.topic="ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[9];datatype=String"
msg.payload=global.get("nazwa9")
return msg
```

[image]

However it doesn't work. The 2nd node is working but in total I would have like 150+ blocks connected to OPC UA Client block. So my question is: does anyone know if there's a way to inject multiple payloads with different topics, favorabily with function, instead of doing it one by one with inject blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#multiple-messages) explains how to send multiple messages from a status node.

With the code you have currently, as soon as it reaches the first `return` statement, the Function node stops processing any further so only one message is sent.

To send multiple messages from a Function node you have two options.

1. return an array of message objects to send.
2. call `node.send(msg);` for each message you want to send.

For example:

```
return [
 [
   { topic: "ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[0];datatype=String", payload: global.get("nazwa")},
   { topic: "ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[1];datatype=String", payload: global.get("nazwa2")},
   { topic: "ns=2;s=Target01.Nazwa.Nazwa[9];datatype=String", payload: global.get("nazwa9")}
  ]
]
```